# Internal files not 'available' on Android - File.exists() returns false for any file

Tags: java, android, file, internal-storage, geopackage

I am trying to access a 2.45GB Geopackage file that is stored in internal storage but whenever I try and access it I get a "File does not exist" error.

The gpkg file is being downloaded via DownloadManager into external storage before being copied into internal storage, but when I call `new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "roads.gpkg").exists();`, I get 'false' returned. As well as this, when I run

```
File[] files = getContext().getFilesDir().listFiles();
for(File file : files){
    Log.i("FILE", file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

the file doesnt show.

To make sure it wasn't unexpected behaviour from the DownloadManager or my copy method, I manually copied the file into "Android/data/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files", as well as an 11 byte txt file, 'test.txt', using my Windows laptop. Again, none of these files return true for `File.exists()` or show in the above listFiles() code output (see below).

Here is the full code of when I try to access the file:

```
File geopackage = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "roads.gpkg");
Log.i("GEOPACKAGE", String.format("GPKG File: %s", geopackage.getPath()));
Log.i("GEOPACKAGE", String.format("Exists? %s", geopackage.exists()?"T":"F"));

Log.i("FILE", getContext().getFilesDir().getPath());
File[] files = getContext().getFilesDir().listFiles();
for(File file : files){
   Log.i("FILE", file.getAbsolutePath());
}

//Pass geopackage to a new object that uses the Geopackage-Android library to handle it.
```

Here is the Logcat output:

```
I/GEOPACKAGE: GPKG File: /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/roads.gpkg
I/GEOPACKAGE: Exists? F
I/FILE: /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/DATA_disk_creation_time_its
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/DATA_disk_creation_time_vts_labl_uk.co.alexks.greenroutes_default
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/DATA_disk_creation_time_vts_no_pois_uk.co.alexks.greenroutes_default
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/DATA_disk_creation_time_vts_uk.co.alexks.greenroutes_default
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/DATA_disk_creation_time_vts_inaka_uk.co.alexks.greenroutes_default
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/DATA_disk_creation_time_its_ter
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/com.google.android.gms.maps._m_u
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/_m_t
I/FILE: /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.uk.co.alexks.greenroutes
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/ZoomTables.data
```

And the expected output:

```
I/GEOPACKAGE: GPKG File: /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/roads.gpkg
I/GEOPACKAGE: Exists? T
I/FILE: /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/roads.gpkg
    /data/user/0/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files/test.txt
```

And my Android manifest with the permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For what its worth, I know I should be using File.isFile() to check if a file is valid but that wouldnt help here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: "The gpkg file is being downloaded via DownloadManager into external storage before being copied into internal storage" -- your [mcve] does not show this. "I manually copied the file into "Android/data/uk.co.alexks.greenroutes/files", as well as an 11 byte txt file, 'test.txt', using my Windows laptop" -- those are not going into what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Your laptop has access to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: Thank you, I was under the impression that directory was internal storage, so when I uninstalled the app to test permissions I deleted the file as well, but as I could still see it in the external storage I thought I didn't need to redownload it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out the file really didn't exist in internal storage (I think I uninstalled the app to test permission requests, but I saw a copy of the dataset in "Android/data/package/files/" (external storage) so thought it did exist), and as @CommonWares pointed out in the comments, the Android/data/package/files folder visable from Windows is not internal storage, it is external so copying the files to there did nothing.